# Munkres - Composing Homotopy between Paths

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

In Munkres, page 326 on Fundamental Groups, we have $$ [f] \star [g] = [f \star g]$$ where $f$ is a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$, and $g$ is a path from $x_1$ to $x_2$. $\star$ defines the composition of the two paths. $[f]$ is the path-homotopy equivalence class of $f$. Now, I am just learning this concept, so please let met know if I make a mistake in my wording below!

I am unable to see why $[f \star g] \subset [f] \star [g] $. For example, consider a sample $f_0 \star g_0$ - it is a path from $x_0$ to $x_2$ that **goes through $x_1$.** Now, this could be homotopically equivalent to another path $h_1$ from $x_0$ to $x_2$ that doesn't goes through $x_1$.

$h_1 \in [f \star g]$, therefore.

1. However, by the above equality, should there exist $f_1, g_1 \in [f], [g]$, respectively, such that $h = f_1 \star g_1$? If so, shouldn't this be impossible, since every such composition must cross through $x_1$? Or do they not have to be identically equal, but rather, that there exists a homotopy between $h$ and $f_1 \star g_1$?
2. In Munkres' proof of the inequality, he shows that $\forall f, f' \in [f]$ and $\forall g, g' \in [g]$, such that F is the homotopy between $f, f'$ and G is the homotopy between $g, g'$, $F \star G$ is the homotopy between $f \star g$ and $f' \star g'$. That is, $f' \star g' \in [f \star g]$, so that $ [f] \star [g] \subset [f \star g]$. Why is this a proof of the above equality? Where is my understanding wrong?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the definition of $[f]\star[g]$.  This is *defined* to be $[f\star g]$ after the latter is shown not to depend on representatives.

Comment: It's a definition, that is $[f] \star [g]$ is defined to be the equivalence class of paths $[f \star g]$. Prior to this, $\star$ is only defined between two paths with matching endpoints, not between two equivalence classes.

Comment: One other thing: the path homotopy class class $[f] \star [g] = [f * g]$ does indeed contain all paths of the form $f_1 * g_1$ such that $f_1$ is path homotopic to $f$ and $g_1$ is path homotopic to $g$. But it can contain a lot more than that. For the path $h$ to be in $[f]\star[g]$ implies that $h$ goes from $x_0$ to $x_2$ and is path homotopic to $f\star g$, but $h$ does *not* necessarily have to pass through $x_1$.